# Running Angular9 and protractor e2e tests prohibitively slow

Tags: angular, testing, protractor

Since upgrading to Angular V9 it has become non-viable to run e2e tests. Even making a small change in the e2e code results in the entire app being rebuilt (which is a matter of minutes) - and i'm not even changing the app code.

```sh
$ ng e2e --port=4202 --webdriver-update=false
```

is there a way to just rerun the tests while retaining the compiled/built app code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workflow that works for me:

**in terminal 1:**

```sh
$ ng serve
```

this is the standard angular "run the server", which does incremental compiles when app code changes are detected - really quickly, and keeps the server running.

**in terminal 2:**

```sh
$ protractor e2e/protractor.conf.js
```

run this when you have made code changes to your e2e test code.

this enables me to make changes and rerun tests really quickly, with the server reacting to app code changes as and when required.